# Human dominated by hamsters

Tags: humans, water, conflict

In a world dominated by hamsters, how would people solve the conflict of drinking water shortages?

Comment: This is very broad. What causes the shortages? Specify more on how the shortages are created as to aid in the answering of how they will be amended. This might have to be broken up into multiple questions.

Comment: Hamsters will provide drinking water for their pet humans.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE, ElverGalarga, your opening gambit of a question is a breathtaking step into the speculative unknown. More information about hamster domination over humans and its relationship to water shortages & consequent conflict would definitely improve the question. Have fun here!

Comment: The hampsters are just middle management.  It is the white lab mice which, as the physical expression of higher dimensional intelligences, are really in charge.

Comment: I would certainly be interested in what way hamster are able to dominate humans. People are strong, faster, have better vision, smarter, and social structures. If we have to rise up against our hamster overlords, it would be nice to figure out in what way they are dominant and thus a target for resistance.

Comment: We'll take on ridiculous questions (you'd be surprised how interesting a ridiculous question can be), but they need to be answerable without simply shooting in the dark.  We're shooting in the dark on this one.  To limit the question to something acceptable, you would need to provide a whole bunch of details that limit the scope.  (ratio of hamsters to humans, number of hamsters, what causes a 1lb hamster to need so much water, why the hamsters are dominant, etc., etc., etc.).

Comment: May we assume that these hamsters are rodents of unusual size?

Comment: There is a desperately needed clarification here.  Is the conflict between humans themselves, siphoning one another's giant water bottles?  Or is this about the heroic human resistance defending their water from vicious alpha hamsters?  ("You want our water bottles?  **MOLON LABE!!**")

Comment: roflmao (I'd be more concerned about the odor:)